# Converting SQL to EXCEL Formula

Tags: sql, excel

`select aColumn, cColumn where cColumn <= 0.2 or cColumn <= -0.2`

How can i convert this code into excel formula?

Comment: You need `FILTER()` function.

Comment: then i just copy the sql into the bracket? (sory im newbie in excel)

Comment: `=FILTER(A:B,(B:B<=0.2)+(B:B<=-0.2))`. Try this one. Post few sample data then desired output.